# CPU under full load java web app (tomcat)

Tags: java

I've tomcat running on my Macbook pro and a web application.
Making a request to a servlet (below i'm showing post method code) and tipping top command in terminal show a java process with 200/300% cpu usage.
The servlet make a request to a mongo database to retrieve 389 documents and then iterate over this documents,process the text with a language detector and Stanford ner classifier, and index it to a local solr server.
Is it normal? Can i improve code or something else to reduce cpu load?

this is the code

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
     throws ServletException, IOException {

  SolrServer server = null;
  try {
     server = new CommonsHttpSolrServer(conf.getString("solr.url"));
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }

  if (req.getParameter("delete") != null) {

     try {

        server.deleteByQuery("*:*");
        server.commit();
     } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
     }
  }

  BasicDBObject findUsersQuery = new BasicDBObject();
  findUsersQuery.put("indexed", false);
  DBCursor cur = uColl.find(findUsersQuery);
  int i = 0;
  while (cur.hasNext()) {
     Collection<SolrInputDocument> usersProfiles = new ArrayList<SolrInputDocument>();
     // String containing comma separated entities like places, organizations
     String namedEntities = "";
     // String containing other terms associated to facebook user
     String bagOfWords = "";

     CrowdUser user = Converter.toObject(CrowdUser.class, cur.next());
     log.debug("Indexing User:" + user.getFacebook().getFacebookID() + " "
           + user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser().getFirstName() + " "
           + user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser().getLastName());
     FacebookUser fu = user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser();

     // Hometown
     if (fu.getHometown() != null) {
        String name = fu.getHometown().getName();
        log.debug("Location:" + name);
        if (name != null) {
           namedEntities += name + " ";
        }

     }
     // Location
     if (fu.getLocation() != null) {
        String name = fu.getLocation().getName();
        log.debug("Hometown:" + name);
        if (name != null) {
           namedEntities += name + " ";
        }

     }
     // Work
     for (FacebookWork work : fu.getWork()) {
        log.debug("Works:");
        String description = work.getDescription();
        String lang = "";
        if (description != null)
           lang = detector.detectLang(description);
        if (description != null && "en".equals(lang)) {
           log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
           ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(description,
                 serializedClassifier);
           namedEntities += result.get(1);
           bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
        }
        if (work.getEmployer() != null && work.getEmployer().getName() != null)
           namedEntities += work.getEmployer().getName() + " ";
        if (work.getPosition() != null && work.getPosition().getName() != null)
           namedEntities += work.getPosition().getName() + " ";
        if (work.getLocation() != null && work.getLocation().getName() != null)
           namedEntities += work.getLocation().getName() + " ";

     }
     // Education
     for (FacebookEducation education : fu.getEducation()) {
        log.debug("Education:");
        if (education.getSchool() != null && education.getSchool().getName() != null)
           namedEntities += education.getSchool().getName() + " ";
        if (education.getDegree() != null && education.getDegree().getName() != null)
           namedEntities += education.getSchool().getName() + " ";
        if (education.getConcentration() != null) {
           for (FacebookDataType concentration : education.getConcentration()) {
              namedEntities += concentration.getName() + " ";
           }
        }

     }

     String about = fu.getAbout();
     if (about != null) {
        String[] strings = about.split("\\n");
        for (String string : strings) {
           log.debug("About: " + string);
           String lang = detector.detectLang(string);
           log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
           if ("en".equals(lang)) {
              ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(string,
                    serializedClassifier);
              namedEntities += result.get(1);
              bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
           }

        }
     }

     String bio = fu.getBio();
     if (bio != null) {
        String[] strings = bio.split("\\n");
        for (String string : strings) {
           log.debug("Bio: " + string);
           String lang = detector.detectLang(string);
           log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
           if ("en".equals(lang)) {
              ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(string,
                    serializedClassifier);
              namedEntities += result.get(1);
              bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
           }

        }
     }

     String quotes = fu.getQuotes();
     if (quotes != null) {
        String[] strings = quotes.split("\\n");
        for (String string : strings) {
           log.debug("Quote: " + string);
           String lang = detector.detectLang(string);
           log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
           if ("en".equals(lang)) {
              ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(string,
                    serializedClassifier);
              namedEntities += result.get(1);
              bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
           }

        }
     }

     String political = fu.getPolitical();
     log.debug("Political : " + political);
     if (political != null)
        namedEntities += political + " ";

     String religion = fu.getReligion();
     log.debug("Religion : " + religion);
     if (religion != null)
        namedEntities += religion + " ";

     if (fu.getWebsite() != null) {
        String HTMLtext = URLUtils.getURLContent(user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser()
              .getWebsite());
        if (HTMLtext != null) {
           String parsedText = Jsoup.parse(HTMLtext).text();
           log.debug("Web Site Content: " + parsedText);
           // log.debug("Language detected: " + detector.detectLang(parsedText));
           ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(parsedText,
                 serializedClassifier);
           namedEntities += result.get(1);
           bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
        }
     }

     ArrayList<FacebookDocument> pages = (ArrayList<FacebookDocument>) MongoUtils
           .getDocumentsByFacebookID(dColl, user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser()
                 .getFacebookPages_id());

     for (FacebookDocument doc : pages) {

        FacebookPage page = (FacebookPage) doc;

        log.debug("Page: " + page.getFacebook_id() + " " + page.getName());

        if (page.getCategory() != null)
           bagOfWords += page.getCategory() + " ";

        if (page.getDescription() != null) {
           String[] strings = page.getDescription().split("\\n");
           for (String string : strings) {
              log.debug("Page description: " + string);
              String lang = detector.detectLang(string);
              log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
              if ("en".equals(lang)) {
                 string = Jsoup.parse(string).text();
                 ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(string,
                       serializedClassifier);
                 namedEntities += result.get(1);
                 bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
              }

           }
        }
        String name = page.getName();
        if (name != null) {
           log.debug("Page name: " + name);
           String lang = detector.detectLang(name);
           log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
           ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(name,
                 serializedClassifier);
           if ("en".equals(lang)) {
              namedEntities += result.get(1);
              bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
           } else {
              namedEntities += result.get(1);
           }

        }

        HashMap<String, String> others = page.getOthers();
        for (String key : others.keySet()) {
           try {
              log.debug("Key: " + key + " Value: " + others.get(key));
              if (key.equals("location")) {
                 try {
                    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
                    JsonNode location = mapper
                          .readValue(others.get(key), JsonNode.class);
                    if (location.get("state") != null)
                       namedEntities += location.get("state").getTextValue() + " ";
                    if (location.get("country") != null)
                       namedEntities += location.get("country").getTextValue() + " ";
                    if (location.get("city") != null)
                       namedEntities += location.get("city").getTextValue() + " ";

                 } catch (Exception e) {
                    log.debug("Parsing Error");
                 }

              } else if (!key.equals("founded") && !key.equals("is_published")
                    && !key.equals("hours") && !key.equals("username")) {

                 String[] strings = others.get(key).split("\\n");
                 for (String string : strings) {
                    String lang = detector.detectLang(string);
                    log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
                    if ("en".equals(lang)) {
                       string = Jsoup.parse(string).text();
                       ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(string,
                             serializedClassifier);
                       namedEntities += result.get(1);
                       bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
                    }

                 }
              }
           } catch (NullPointerException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
           }
        }

     }

     ArrayList<FacebookDocument> groups = (ArrayList<FacebookDocument>) MongoUtils
           .getDocumentsByFacebookID(dColl, user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser()
                 .getFacebookGroups_id());

     for (FacebookDocument doc : groups) {

        FacebookGroup group = (FacebookGroup) doc;
        log.debug("Group: " + group.getFacebook_id() + " " + group.getName());

        if (group.getDescription() != null) {
           String[] strings = group.getDescription().split("\\n");
           for (String string : strings) {
              log.debug("Group description: " + string);
              String lang = detector.detectLang(string);
              log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
              if ("en".equals(lang)) {
                 string = Jsoup.parse(string).text();
                 ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(string,
                       serializedClassifier);
                 namedEntities += result.get(1);
                 bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
              }

           }
        }
        String name = group.getName();
        if (name != null) {
           log.debug("Group name: " + name);
           String lang = detector.detectLang(name);
           log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
           ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(name,
                 serializedClassifier);
           if ("en".equals(lang)) {
              namedEntities += result.get(1);
              bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
           } else {
              namedEntities += result.get(1);
           }
        }
        if (group.getDiscussions() != null) {
           String discussion = "";
           for (FacebookDiscussion disc : group.getDiscussions()) {

              String message = disc.getMessage();
              log.debug("Discussion: " + message);
              if (message != null && "en".equals(detector.detectLang(message))) {
                 discussion += message + ".\n";

              }

              if (disc.getComments() != null) {
                 for (String comment : disc.getComments()) {
                    log.debug("Comment:" + comment);
                    if ("en".equals(detector.detectLang(comment))) {
                       discussion += comment + ".\n";
                    }

                 }
              }

           }
           ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(discussion,
                 serializedClassifier);
           namedEntities += result.get(1);
           bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
        }

     }

     log.debug("NamedEntities: " + namedEntities);
     log.debug("bagOfWords: " + bagOfWords);

     SolrInputDocument doc1 = new SolrInputDocument();
     doc1.addField("id", user.getFacebook().getFacebookID(), 1.0f);
     doc1.addField("name", user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser().getFirstName() + " "
           + user.getFacebook().getFacebookUser().getLastName(), 1.0f);
     doc1.addField("bagofwords", bagOfWords, 1.0f);
     doc1.addField("namedentities", namedEntities);
     usersProfiles.add(doc1);
     try {
        server.add(usersProfiles);
        server.commit();
        user.setIndexed(true);
        MongoUtils.updateUserData(uColl, user);

     } catch (SolrServerException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        log.debug("Not committed");
     }
     i++;

     log.debug("Indexed Profile Number:" + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: No, it's not normal to get more CPU usage than the machine can provide (200-300%?). And I don't know about anything else, but _please_ break this up into smaller methods - among other things, it'll allow more targeted profiling.

Comment: @X-Zero: It's normal if you have more than one CPU core.

Comment: @palacsint - On windows at least, total output always maxes out at 100%. Two cores would max out at 50% (of total) each.

Comment: @X-Zero: Yes, you're right. Macbook Pro also could run Windows, but top usually a Unix/Linux command :-)

Comment: yes it's normal on unix, but i'm asking if (in your opinion) it is normal for this kind of code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips:

1. Use `StringBuilder` instead of string concatenation. (`namedEntities`, `bagOfWords`)
2. Maybe you should close the cursor at the end of the method.

Some other notes:

1. Handle exceptions. Why don't you log them with the `log` object as well? Or should they have proper handling?
2. Do not reuse variables. The `string` variable in the following snippet is confusing:

   ```
   for (String string : strings) {
       log.debug("Group description: " + string);
       String lang = detector.detectLang(string);
       log.debug("Language detected: " + lang);
       if ("en".equals(lang)) {
           string = Jsoup.parse(string).text();
           ArrayList<String> result = NERUtils.getNamedEntities(string,
              serializedClassifier);
           namedEntities += result.get(1);
           bagOfWords += result.get(0) + " ";
       }

   }
   ```

   Declare a new variable inside the condition:

   ```
   final String string = Jsoup.parse(string).text();
   ```
3. Use meaningful variable names. `string` is not readable as a variable name.

   ```
   String[] strings = others.get(key).split("\\n");
   for (String string : strings) {
   ```

   What does it store? It could be `keyLine`, for example.
4. As *@X-Zero* already mentioned, extract out some methods with descriptive names. It would improve readability a lot.
5. ```
   ArrayList<String> result ...
   ```

   should be

   ```
   List<String> result ...
   ```

   [Type List vs type ArrayList in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2279030/type-list-vs-type-arraylist-in-java)